# How to extract tags from html content using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, html-parsing

I have something similar to the following html code, and I am trying to parse / extract some content from this.

```
<div class="row d-3">
    <div class="col-16 col-sm-8">
        <strong>Category</strong> <br>
        // *** extract this text ***
        Clothing</div>
    <div class="col-16 col-sm-8">
        <strong>Sub-category</strong> <br>
          // *** extract this text ***
         this is Sub-category
        </div>
    <div class="col-16 col-sm-8">
        <strong>product</strong> <br>
        // *** extract this text ***
        This is the actual product </div>
</div>
```

I need the following:

{
Category: Clothing,
Sub-category: This is sub-category,
product: This is the actual product
}.

I tried the following:

```
for b in soup.find_all("div", class_="row d-3"):
  print(b.strong.get_text())
```

but I am only able to extract `Category` but not `Clothing`.

Comment: What have you tried so far, can you improve your question by adding code and the expected output? Would be great - Thanks

Comment: Added more info to the question. Please let me know if that is helpful

Answer (score 0):

#### How to achieve?

You can take use of `contents` or in following solution of `stripped_strings` that is a generator

```
list(b.stripped_strings)

#Output --> ['Category', 'Clothing', 'Sub-category', 'this is Sub-category', 'product', 'This is the actual product']
```

To convert this resultset in a dict you can use:

```
dict({x for x in zip(s[::2],s[1::2])})
```

#### Exmple:

```
html = '''
<div class="row d-3">
    <div class="col-16 col-sm-8">
        <strong>Category</strong> <br>
        Clothing</div>
    <div class="col-16 col-sm-8">
        <strong>Sub-category</strong> <br>
         this is Sub-category
        </div>
    <div class="col-16 col-sm-8">
        <strong>product</strong> <br>
        This is the actual product </div>
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

for b in soup.find_all("div", class_="row d-3"):
    s = list(b.stripped_strings)
    print(dict({x for x in zip(s[::2],s[1::2])}))
```

#### Output:

```
{'Category': 'Clothing', 'Sub-category': 'this is Sub-category', 'product': 'This is the actual product'}
```